# LCM HCF (factors)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A number has exactly six factors , two of the factors are 9 and 15. List all the factors of the number .

First I found LCM of 9 and 15, and then I'm stuck and not sure how to carry on..
Can I get a hint. Thanks in advance !

Comment: And, what is the LCM of $9$ and $15$?  How many factors does it have?

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean non-trivial factors, or also trivial factor? We see that this number $n$ is

$$n \equiv 0 \mod 9$$

and

$$n \equiv 0 \mod 15.$$

What you may want to consider is the fact that any number that divides either $9$ and $15$ also divides $n$ by transitivity of the "divides" statement. In this case, $3$ should divide $n$ since $3 \mid 9 \wedge 3 \mid 15$. Since $5 \mid 15$ and $15 \mid n$, then $5 \mid n.$ Since the LCM of $9$ and $15$ is $45$, $45 \mid n$. If we include trivial factors, $1$ and $n$ also divide $n$. Thus, the 6 factors (not including $n$) are

$$1,3,5,9,15,45.$$

Answer (score 1):

Given a positive integer $x$ and its prime factorization as $x=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$

$x$ will have $(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)\cdots(\alpha_k+1)$ factors.

Specifically, its factors will all be of the form $p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}\cdots p_k^{\beta_k}$ where $0\leq \beta_i\leq \alpha_i$ for each $i$.  Each choice of $(\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots)$ will yield a factor.

For example, $24=2^3\cdot 3^1$ so $24$ has $(3+1)(1+1)=4\cdot 2=8$ factors.  Specifically they are $2^03^0,2^13^0,2^23^0,2^3,3^0,2^03^1,2^13^1,2^23^1,2^33^1$, or written a different way: $1,2,4,8,3,6,12,24$.

For your specific problem, if you are told that $9\mid n$ and $15\mid n$, you know that $lcm(9,15)\mid n$.

Further, we know that if $a\mid b$ and $a\neq b$, that $\#\text{of factors}(a)<\#\text{of factors}(b)$

We know that $lcm(9,15)=45 = 3^2\cdot 5^1$

How many factors does $45$ have?  Could there be a larger $n$ than $45$ that satisfies the desired properties and has $6$ factors?